# Transformer design problem

Tags: current, pcb-design, transformer, ac, overheat

*I will try my best because my English is not the best. Thanks!*

I'm designing a transformer for a PCB that I made. The circuit in the PCB accepts 5 V to 20 V in.

So the transformer that I made is for 220 VAC 50 Hz but you can put 380 VAC, because (this is the part when I don't know if it's okay). I will have in the output of the transformer this:

220VAC-10VAC and 380VAC -> (380 VAC × 10 VAC) / 220 VAC = 17.27 V.

And yes, I did it and it functions perfectly, but it gets hot when I apply 380 VAC. This is the data of the transformer I made:

- Vout: 8 V . Vrms: 8 V / (root 2) = 5.65 + 2.3 V for losses and diodes. = 8 V
- I Secondary max: 0.25 A
- I Primary max : 2 W / 220 V = 0.009 A = 9 mA
- Potency: 0.25 A × 8 V = 2W
- Core: 2 cm × 1 cm = 2 cm<sup>2</sup>
- Pmax Core: 2 cm<sup>2</sup> × 2 cm<sup>2</sup>2 = 4 W
- V1/V2= 220 / 8 V = 27.5
- Turns = 42 / (2 cm<sup>2</sup>) = 21 Turns x volt
- Pturns= 21 × 220 V = 4620 Turns
- Sturns = 21 × 8 V = 168 Turns
- Diameter of primary: 0.09 mm
- Diameter of secondary: 0.25 mm

I used copper non-oriented grain silicon steel, thickness: 0.5 mm, losses: 1.8 - 2.2 W/kg

The circuit doesn't consume more than 100 mA when it gets hot, I think that the primary more. The transformer also vibrates more than normal, so I suppose that it's overloaded. Should I add more turns? Should I add more thickness to the copper?

Comment: If you edit the question there is a tool that you can use to draw a schematic of the circuit

Comment: @VoltageSpike for what you need the schematic, my circuits its fine, and consume the current i said, i tested that with another transformer!

Comment: You seem to have computed the (primary) windings from the lower voltage. Check the nominal voltages and tolerance bands - in Europe, voltages were "harmonised" to 230/400 V one third of a century ago, and deviation to higher voltages raised from +6 % back to +10 % in 2009. You may be applying 440 V to a 220 V winding. A mains frequency transformer may not be your best bet. Many appliances specified for AC accept DC, but don't exceed 3/4 of specified max if you try that.

Comment: How did you come up with 21 turns/V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are running in to core saturation issues.

The minimum number of turns to prevent saturation is given by
$$  N = {E_{pk} \over {\omega \cdot B_{pk} \cdot A_e}} $$
Where:
\$ E_{pk}\$ = peak sine wave voltage. Multiply by 1.57 for a symmetrical square wave.
\$\omega\$ = radian frequency = \$2\pi f\$
\$A_e\$ = effective area of the core [\$m^2\$] (refer to the core data sheet)
\$B_{pk}\$ = peak flux density when the core saturates [\$T\$] (refer to the core data sheet)

Silicon steels generally saturate in the 1.1 to 1.5 Tesla region.

When designing transformers, I like to keep the magnetizing inductive reactance >5x higher than the load (or reflected load) impedance so the magnetizing current isn't significant compared to the load current.

Answer (score 0):

In a transformer, the voltage per turn depends on the core flux.

If you want more voltage, so going from 220 V to 380 V input, one option is to increase the number of primary turns by 380/220.

The other option is to increase the core flux. Increasing the core area by this ratio will increase the core flux without increasing the flux density.

Most transformers are designed so that their peak flux density runs fairly close to core saturation. If you simply apply more primary volts, you move them closer to saturation, or into saturation, where the primary inductance plummets, and the magnetising current increases by an order of magnitude or more to smoke the transformer.